# boto s3 python library exceptions

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

I am trying the delete the keys in a particular bucket and if the key has successfully deleted then only want to perform next step otherwise retry the deletion in S3.

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection, Bucket, Key
bucket = 'test-bucket'
object = Key(bucket=bucket, name='xyxabc')

# delete the object from the S3
object.delete()
```

Does boto library provide any exception (I did not find one) which can be used to validate object.delete() call?

Comment: Where do you import `Key` from? Can you add your imports to the example? It looks like you meant `S3.Object`, not `Key`.

Comment: Added as suggested by you.

Answer (score 1):

### Short answer

[`boto.s3.key.Key.delete()`](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/2.6.0/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.key.Key.delete) raises a [`boto.exception.S3ResponseError`](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/2.6.0/ref/boto.html?highlight=s3responseerror#boto.exception.S3ResponseError) if there's any error response from S3.

That said, you should check which error is it, if raised. It can be any of [S3 error responses](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/ErrorResponses.html).

### More details

[`boto.s3.key.Key.delete()`](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/2.6.0/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.key.Key.delete) just calls [`boto.s3.bucket.Bucket.delete_key()`](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/2.6.0/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.bucket.Bucket.delete_key).

It seems like [`boto.s3.bucket.Bucket.delete_key()`](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/2.6.0/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.bucket.Bucket.delete_key) internally checks the response from S3, and if it's not an `HTTP 204 NoContent` response, it raises a `storage_response_error` from its provider, which is a [`boto.exception.S3ResponseError`](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/2.6.0/ref/boto.html?highlight=s3responseerror#boto.exception.S3ResponseError).